# Allow user to resize groupbox columns

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a groupbox with 3 columns, how would i allow users to resize the column size?

Inside each groupbox column is another groupbox with a textbox set to fill the area. When the user maximizes the form I want the groupbox columns to be able to be resized by the user.

Edit...
This is a winforms application

Edit again....
I have now inspected it alittle closer and whats actually going on is I have a main groupbox with a TableLayoutPanel with 3 columns with a group box inside each column. (Sorry this is a really old project that im bringing to life.

Comment: Since when does a GroupBox have columns?

Comment: In the properties for the groupbox you can set the columnCount aswel as the row count

Comment: Why don't you use a TableLayoutPanel to achieve this?

Comment: @user3298624 Check [GroupBox WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) or [GroupBox WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx), also I opened Visual Studio and added a GroupBox to a form, no property `ColumnCount`.

Comment: Just tried the TableLayoutPanel control and am faced with the same problem, when i run the app im still not able to expand the the qroupboxes in the columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) control. It gives you two panels in which to place other controls, including more SplitContainers.

So if you drop one on your form, then drop a second one inside one of the panels on the first, you'll have three "columns" where you can place each of your GroupBoxes.

[image]

Then you could set `IsSplitterFixed = true` on the splitters initially, to disable resizing the panels, then re-enable them if the user maximizes the window:

```
private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized;
    splitContainer2.IsSplitterFixed = WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```